# C# algo required for creating cluster

Tags: c#, linq, graph-algorithm

I have a Generic list say `List<TransactionInfo>`

`TransactionInfo` class have three properties:-

```
public long TransactionId { get; set; }
public string BuyerName { get; set; }  
public string SellerName { get; set; }
```

If below is data in my list:-

```
1 A B   
2 A C
3 A D
4 G H
5 C M
6 D E
7 A F
8 H L
9 L R
10 Y Z
```

Then I want to create group clusters based on the transactions between members. I want to write LINQ query that should return new List

ClusterInfo Class contains one property:-

```
public List<TransactionInfo> Transactions { get; set; }
```

`List<ClusterInfo>` should contain:-

clusters[0]:-

```
1 A B
2 A C
3 A D
5 C M
6 D E
7 A F
```

clusters[1]

```
4 G H
8 H L
9 L R
```

clusters[2]

```
10 Y Z
```

How these new lists are selected:-
All the direct or indirect Buyers/Sellers should be part of one cluster.

Can anyone help me in writing LINQ query to achieve this. If not LINQ then simple for loop solution will also suffice.

PS :- posting this from mobile.. so plz excuse bad formatting

Comment: What you want to achieve is called "To find the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of a graph"

Comment: yes sir i need to find connected components and then want to group them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
static public void Main()
{
    // Example of dataset
    List<TransactionInfo> transactionInfos = new List<TransactionInfo>()
    {
        new TransactionInfo(1, "A", "B"),
        new TransactionInfo(2, "A", "C"),
        new TransactionInfo(3, "A", "D"),
        new TransactionInfo(4, "G", "H"),
        new TransactionInfo(5, "C", "M"),
        new TransactionInfo(6, "D", "E"),
        new TransactionInfo(7, "A", "F"),
        new TransactionInfo(8, "H", "L"),
        new TransactionInfo(9, "L", "R"),
        new TransactionInfo(10, "Y", "Z"),
    };

    // Creates the graph and add the arcs
    UndirectedGraph<string> graph = new UndirectedGraph<string>();
    foreach (TransactionInfo transactionInfo in transactionInfos)
        graph.AddArc(transactionInfo.SellerName, transactionInfo.BuyerName);

    var result = (from clusterByNode in graph.GetConnectedComponents()  // Gets the connected components
                  select (from transactionInfo in transactionInfos  // Gets the transaction infos
                          join node in clusterByNode on transactionInfo.BuyerName equals node  // Joins the transactionInfo with the node in the connected component
                          select transactionInfo).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

With the class:

```
public class TransactionInfo
{
    public long TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
    public string SellerName { get; set; }

    public TransactionInfo(long transactionId, string buyerName, string sellerName)
    {
        TransactionId = transactionId;
        BuyerName = buyerName;
        SellerName = sellerName;
    }
}
```

And, the class that find the connected components:

```
public class UndirectedGraph<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>> linkedNodes = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();

    public void AddNode(T node)
    {
        if (!linkedNodes.ContainsKey(node))
            linkedNodes.Add(node, new HashSet<T>());
    }

    public void AddArc(T node1, T node2)
    {
        if (!linkedNodes.ContainsKey(node1))
            linkedNodes.Add(node1, new HashSet<T>());
        linkedNodes[node1].Add(node2);

        if (!linkedNodes.ContainsKey(node2))
            linkedNodes.Add(node2, new HashSet<T>());
        linkedNodes[node2].Add(node1);
    }

    public IEnumerable<HashSet<T>> GetConnectedComponents()
    {
        HashSet<T> visitedNodes = new HashSet<T>();

        foreach (T nodeToVisit in linkedNodes.Keys)
        {
            if (!visitedNodes.Contains(nodeToVisit))
            {
                HashSet<T> connectedComponent = GetConnectedComponent(nodeToVisit);
                visitedNodes.UnionWith(connectedComponent);
                yield return connectedComponent;
            }
        }
    }
    private HashSet<T> GetConnectedComponent(T from)
    {
        HashSet<T> result = new HashSet<T>();

        Stack<T> nodesToVisit = new Stack<T>();
        nodesToVisit.Push(from);
        result.Add(from);

        while (nodesToVisit.Count != 0)
        {
            T nodeToVisit = nodesToVisit.Pop();

            foreach (T linkedNode in linkedNodes[nodeToVisit])
            {
                if (!result.Contains(linkedNode))
                {
                    nodesToVisit.Push(linkedNode);
                    result.Add(linkedNode);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton bro :).. I exactly wanted this result set. Thanks a lot from the bottom of my heart. You have saved my day by giving this code :)